# Tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

I have subclassed tkinter treeview object added many features like cut,paste etc and context menus to insert rows, delete etc. Would like some feedback on how well it works and if it's intuitive or not.

Current version is @: https://github.com/unodan/TkInter-Treeview-Example-Demo

```
import json
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.font as tkfont

from os import path, makedirs
from sys import platform
from datetime import datetime

ABS_PATH = path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__))

_IID = 0
_TYPE = 1
_OPEN = 2
_TAGS = 3
_SIZE = 4
_MODIFIED = 5
_DATA1 = 6

_SKIP = 0
_CANCEL = 1


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

        self.app_data = {}

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use('clam')

        self.title('Treeview Demo')
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.exit)

        self.platform = platform
        if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
            self.platform = 'linux'

        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        def setup_app():
            file = path.join(ABS_PATH, 'app.json')
            if path.exists(file):
                with open(file) as f:
                    self.app_data = json.load(f)
            else:
                self.app_data = {
                    'geometry': '500x700',
                }

        def setup_treeview():
            tv_line_padding = 8
            tv_heading_padding = 5
            tv_heading_border_width = 2
            font = tkfont.nametofont('TkDefaultFont')
            self.linespace = font.metrics('linespace')
            row_height = self.linespace + tv_line_padding
            tv_indent = row_height
            self.style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=row_height)
            self.style.configure('Treeview.Heading', padding=tv_heading_padding, borderwidth=tv_heading_border_width)
            self.style.configure('Treeview', indent=tv_indent)

            self.style.configure('TEntry', selectbackground='#0081c1')
            self.style.map('Treeview', background=[('selected', '#0081c1')])

            self.style.configure('TCombobox', selectbackground='#0081c1')
            self.style.map(
                'TCombobox',
                foreground=[('readonly', 'white')],
                fieldbackground=[('readonly', '#0081c1')],
            )
            self.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Background", 'white')
            self.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Foreground", '#000000')

            file = path.join(ABS_PATH, 'treeview.json')
            if path.exists(file):
                with open(file) as f:
                    setup = json.load(f)
            else:
                now = datetime.now()
                dt_string = now.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
                setup = {
                    'headings': (
                        {'text': 'Name', 'anchor': tk.W},
                        {'text': 'IID', 'anchor': tk.W},
                        {'text': 'Item', 'anchor': tk.W},
                        {'text': 'Open', 'anchor': tk.W},
                        {'text': 'Tags', 'anchor': tk.W},
                        {'text': 'Size', 'anchor': tk.W},
                        {'text': 'Last Modified', 'anchor': tk.W},
                        {'text': 'Data', 'anchor': tk.W},
                    ),
                    'columns': (
                        {'width': 180, 'minwidth': 3, 'stretch': tk.NO, 'type': 'Entry', 'unique': True},
                        {'width': 70, 'minwidth': 3, 'stretch': tk.NO},
                        {'width': 70, 'minwidth': 3, 'stretch': tk.NO},
                        {'width': 70, 'minwidth': 3, 'stretch': tk.NO},
                        {'width': 120, 'minwidth': 3, 'stretch': tk.NO},
                        {'width': 80, 'minwidth': 3, 'stretch': tk.NO},
                        {'width': 130, 'minwidth': 3, 'stretch': tk.NO},
                        {'width': 180, 'minwidth': 3, 'stretch': tk.YES, 'type': 'Combobox',
                            'values': ('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3', 'Value 4', 'Value 5'),
                         },
                    ),
                    'data': (
                        {'text': 'Folder 0', 'open': 1, 'values': ('', 'Node', True, '', '', dt_string, ''),
                         'children': (
                             {'text': 'photo1.png', 'values': ('', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', dt_string, '')},
                             {'text': 'photo2.png', 'values': ('', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', dt_string, '')},
                             {'text': 'photo3.png', 'values': ('', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', dt_string, '')},
                             {'text': 'Folder 0_1', 'open': 1, 'values': ('', 'Node', True, '', '', dt_string, ''),
                              'children': (
                                  {'text': 'photo1.png', 'values': ('', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', dt_string, '')},
                                  {'text': 'photo2.png', 'values': ('', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', dt_string, '')},
                                  {'text': 'photo3.png', 'values': ('', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', dt_string, '')},
                              )},
                         )},
                        {'text': 'Folder 1', 'open': 1, 'values': ('', 'Node', True, '', '', dt_string, ''),
                         'children': (
                             {'text': 'photo4.png', 'values': ('', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', dt_string, '')},
                             {'text': 'photo5.png', 'values': ('', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', dt_string, '')},
                             {'text': 'photo6.png', 'values': ('', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', dt_string, '')},
                         )},
                    ),
                }

            tree = self.treeview = Treeview(self.frame, setup=setup)
            tree.focus_set()

            settings = dict(setup.get('settings', ()))
            item = settings.get('focus', None)
            if (not item or not tree.exists(item)) and tree.get_children():
                item = tree.get_children()[0]

            view = settings.get('view', None)
            if view:
                self.treeview.xview('moveto', view[0])
                self.treeview.yview('moveto', view[1])

            tree.focus(item)
            tree.selection_add(item)
            tree.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW, row=0, column=0)

        setup_app()
        setup_treeview()

        self.geometry(self.app_data['geometry'])

    def exit(self):
        self.app_data.update({'geometry': self.geometry()})

        self.save()
        self.destroy()

    def save(self):
        file = path.join(ABS_PATH, 'app.json')
        if file:
            dirname = path.dirname(file)
            if not path.exists(dirname):
                makedirs(dirname)

            with open(file, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(self.app_data, f, indent=3)

        file = path.join(ABS_PATH, 'treeview.json')
        if file:
            dirname = path.dirname(file)
            if not path.exists(dirname):
                makedirs(dirname)

            with open(file, 'w') as f:
                data = self.treeview.serialize()
                data['settings'] = tuple({
                    'view': (self.treeview.xview()[0], self.treeview.yview()[0]),
                    'focus': self.treeview.focus()
                }.items())

                for idx, c in enumerate(self.treeview.columns):
                    c['width'] = self.treeview.column(f'#{idx}', 'width')

                json.dump(data, f, indent=3)


class Event:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x, self.y = None, None


class DialogBase(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        width = kwargs.pop('width', None)
        height = kwargs.pop('height', None)
        title = kwargs.pop('title', '')
        resizable = kwargs.pop('resizable', (True, True))
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        self.resizable(*resizable)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.results = None
        self.container = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.container.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

        self.options = kwargs

        geometry = self.geometry().split('+', 1)
        _width, _height = geometry[0].split('x')
        if width:
            _width = width
        if height:
            _height = height

        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f'{_width}x{_height}+{geometry[1]}')


class RenameDialog(DialogBase):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        message = kwargs.pop('message', 'No Message!')
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.container.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        frame = self.row0 = ttk.Frame(self.container)
        frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.label = ttk.Label(frame, text=message)
        self.label.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.EW, pady=(0, 10), row=0, column=0)

        self.entry = Entry(frame, width=30)
        self.entry.config(textvariable=self.entry.var)
        self.entry.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW, row=1, column=0, padx=(5, 0))
        frame.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.EW, padx=10, pady=(20, 0))

        frame = self.row1 = ttk.Frame(self.container)
        frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.button_rename = ttk.Button(frame, text="Rename", width=8)
        self.button_rename.grid(sticky=tk.NS + tk.E, row=0, column=0, padx=(5, 0))
        self.button_skip = ttk.Button(frame, text="Skip", width=8)
        self.button_skip.grid(sticky=tk.NS + tk.E, row=0, column=1, padx=(5, 0))
        self.button_cancel = ttk.Button(frame, text="Cancel", width=8)
        self.button_cancel.grid(sticky=tk.NS+tk.E, row=0, column=2, padx=(5, 0))

        frame.grid(row=1, sticky=tk.EW+tk.S, padx=10, pady=(10, 20))


class MessageDialog(DialogBase):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        message = kwargs.pop('message', '')
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        frame = self.row0 = ttk.Frame(self.container)
        frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.label = ttk.Label(frame, text=message)
        self.label.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW, pady=5, row=0, column=0)
        frame.grid(sticky=tk.EW, padx=10, pady=(20, 0))

        frame = self.row1 = ttk.Frame(self.container)
        frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.button_ok = ttk.Button(frame, text="Okay")
        self.button_ok.grid(sticky=tk.NS + tk.E, row=0, column=0, padx=(5, 0))
        frame.grid(row=1, sticky=tk.EW, padx=10, pady=(10, 20))


class Text(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.origin_x = self.origin_y = 0


class Frame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.scroll_x = \
            self.scroll_y = None


class Entry(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.configure(textvariable=self.var)

        self.undo_data = {}
        self.popup = \
            self.menu_background = None
        self.style = ttk.Style()

        self.setup()
        self.bindings_set()

    def setup(self):
        def set_popup_menu():
            opts = dict(self.style.map('Treeview', 'background'))
            background = self.style.lookup('Treeview.Heading', 'background')

            popup = self.popup = tk.Menu(
                self.winfo_toplevel(),
                tearoff=0,
                background=background,
                foreground='#000000',
                activebackground=opts['selected']
            )

            popup.add_command(label="Select All", command=self.select_all)
            popup.add_separator()
            popup.add_command(label="Cut", command=lambda: self.event_generate('<Control-x>'))
            popup.add_command(label="Copy", command=lambda: self.event_generate('<Control-c>'))
            popup.add_command(label="Paste", command=lambda: self.event_generate('<Control-v>'))
            popup.add_separator()
            popup.add_command(label="Delete", command=self.clear)

        self.menu_background = self.style.lookup('TScrollbar.thumb', 'background')
        set_popup_menu()

    def clear(self):
        self.delete(0, tk.END)

    def select_all(self):
        self.select_range(0, tk.END)
        self.icursor(tk.END)

    def popup_menu(self, event):
        if not self.popup:
            return

        wdg = event.widget
        wdg.focus_set()

        self.popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def bindings_set(self):
        bindings = {
            '<ButtonPress-3>': self.popup_menu,
        }
        for command, callback in bindings.items():
            self.bind(command, callback)


class Combobox(ttk.Combobox):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.configure(textvariable=self.var)

        self.popup = \
            self.menu_background = None

        self.style = ttk.Style()

        self.setup()
        self.bindings_set()

    def setup(self):
        def set_popup_menu():
            opts = dict(self.style.map('Treeview', 'background'))
            background = self.style.lookup('Treeview.Heading', 'background')

            popup = self.popup = tk.Menu(
                self.winfo_toplevel(),
                tearoff=0,
                background=background,
                foreground='#000000',
                activebackground=opts['selected']
            )

            popup.add_command(label="Select All", command=self.select_all)
            popup.add_separator()
            popup.add_command(label="Cut", command=lambda: self.event_generate('<Control-x>'))
            popup.add_command(label="Copy", command=lambda: self.event_generate('<Control-c>'))
            popup.add_command(label="Paste", command=lambda: self.event_generate('<Control-v>'))
            popup.add_separator()
            popup.add_command(label="Delete", command=self.clear)

        self.menu_background = self.style.lookup('TScrollbar.thumb', 'background')
        set_popup_menu()

    def select_all(self):
        self.select_range(0, tk.END)
        self.icursor(tk.END)

    def clear(self):
        self.var.set('')

    def popup_menu(self, event):
        if not self.popup:
            return

        wdg = event.widget
        wdg.focus_set()

        self.popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def bindings_set(self):
        bindings = {
            '<ButtonPress-3>': self.popup_menu,
        }
        for command, callback in bindings.items():
            self.bind(command, callback)


class Label(ttk.Label):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        super().__init__(parent, textvariable=self.var, **kwargs)

        self.var.set(kwargs.get('text', ''))


class Listbox(tk.Listbox):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.config(listvariable=self.var)

    def set_row_colors(self, odd, even):
        for i in range(0, len(self.get(0, tk.END))):
            color = odd if i % 2 else even
            self.itemconfig(i, {'bg': color})


class Scrollbar(ttk.Scrollbar):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        self.callback = kwargs.pop('callback', None)
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

    def set(self, low, high):
        if float(low) > 0 or float(high) < 1:
            ttk.Scrollbar.set(self, low, high)
            self.grid()
        else:
            self.grid_remove()

        if self.callback:
            self.callback(self)


class Treeview(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        self.frame = Frame(parent)
        self.frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        setup = kwargs.pop('setup', {})
        data = setup.pop('data', [])
        self.columns = setup['columns']
        self.headings = setup['headings']
        self.scroll = kwargs.pop('scroll', (True, True))

        super().__init__(self.frame, **kwargs)

        self.detached = []
        self.undo_data = {}
        self.sorted_columns = {}

        self.shift = \
            self.popup = \
            self.scroll_x = \
            self.scroll_y = \
            self.selected = \
            self.dlg_results = \
            self.active_popup_widget = \
            self.active_popup_column = \
            self.cursor_offset = \
            self.menu_background = None

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.indent = self.style.lookup('Treeview', 'indent')
        self.rowheight = self.style.lookup('Treeview', 'rowheight')

        if setup:
            self.setup(setup)

        if data:
            self.populate('', data)

        self.bindings_set()
        self.frame.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def setup(self, data):

        def set_style():
            background = self.style.lookup("TFrame", "background")

            self.tag_configure('odd', background=background)
            self.tag_configure('even', background='#ffffff')
            self.troughcolor = self.style.lookup('TScrollbar.trough', 'troughcolor')
            self.menu_background = self.style.lookup('TScrollbar.Heading', 'background')
            self.style.configure(".", indicatorsize=self.rowheight / 2 + 1)

        def set_popup_menu():
            opts = dict(self.style.map('Treeview', 'background'))
            background = self.style.lookup('Treeview.Heading', 'background')

            popup = self.popup = tk.Menu(
                self.winfo_toplevel(),
                tearoff=0,
                background=background,
                foreground='#000000',
                activebackground=opts['selected']
            )
            create_new = tk.Menu(
                popup,
                tearoff=0,
                background=background,
                foreground='#000000',
                activebackground=opts['selected']
            )

            popup.add_cascade(label="Insert", menu=create_new)
            popup.add_separator()
            popup.add_command(label="Cut", command=self.cut)
            popup.add_command(label="Copy", command=self.copy)
            popup.add_command(label="Paste", command=self.paste)
            popup.add_separator()
            popup.add_command(label="Delete", command=self.detach)

            create_new.add_command(label="Item", command=self.insert_leaf)
            create_new.add_separator()
            create_new.add_command(label="Folder", command=self.insert_node)

        def set_scrollbars():
            scroll_x, scroll_y = self.scroll

            if scroll_x:
                sb_x = self.scroll_x = Scrollbar(self.frame, callback=popup_widget_destroy)
                sb_x.configure(command=self.xview, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
                sb_x.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW, row=980, column=0)
                self.configure(xscrollcommand=sb_x.set)

            if scroll_y:
                sb_y = self.scroll_y = Scrollbar(self.frame, callback=popup_widget_destroy)
                sb_y.configure(command=self.yview)
                self.configure(yscrollcommand=sb_y.set)
                sb_y.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW, row=0, column=990)

        def set_rows_columns():
            ids = []
            columns = len(data['columns'])
            for column in range(1, columns):
                ids.append(f'#{column}')
            self["columns"] = ids

            for idx, cfg in enumerate(data['headings']):
                _id = cfg['column'] if 'column' in cfg else f'#{idx}'
                self.heading(_id, text=cfg['text'], anchor=cfg['anchor'])
                self.sorted_columns[f'#{idx}'] = True

            for idx, cfg in enumerate(data['columns']):
                _id = cfg['column'] if 'column' in cfg else f'#{idx}'
                self.column(_id, width=cfg['width'], minwidth=cfg['minwidth'], stretch=cfg['stretch'])

        def popup_widget_destroy(_):
            if self.active_popup_widget:
                self.active_popup_widget.destroy()
                self.active_popup_widget = None

        set_style()
        set_popup_menu()
        set_scrollbars()
        set_rows_columns()
        self.after(1, self.tags_reset)

    def next(self, item):
        if self.item(item, 'open') and self.get_children(item):
            _next = self.get_children(item)[0]
            return _next

        _next = super(Treeview, self).next(item)
        if not _next and self.next(self.parent(item)):
            _next = self.next(self.parent(item))
        return _next

    def prev(self, item):
        _prev = super(Treeview, self).prev(item)
        if not _prev:
            parent = self.parent(item)
            _prev = parent if parent else ''

        return _prev

    def tag_add(self, tags, item):
        self.tags_update('add', tags, item)

    def tag_remove(self, tags, item=None):
        self.tags_update('remove', tags, item)

    def tags_reset(self, excluded=None):
        def reset(_item):
            tags = list(self.item(_item, 'tags'))
            for _tag in tags.copy():
                if _tag not in exclude:
                    tags.pop(tags.index(_tag))
            self.item(_item, tags=tags)

            for node in self.get_children(_item):
                reset(node)

        def set_tag(_item, _tag):
            _tag = 'even' if _tag == 'odd' else 'odd'
            self.tag_add(_tag, _item)
            self.value_set(_TAGS, str(self.item(_item, 'tags')), _item)
            if int(self.item(_item, 'open')):
                for node in self.get_children(_item):
                    _tag = set_tag(node, _tag)
            return _tag

        exclude = []
        if excluded and not isinstance(excluded, tk.Event):
            if isinstance(excluded, str):
                excluded = (excluded,)

            for item in excluded:
                if item in excluded:
                    exclude.append(item)

        tag = 'odd'
        for item in self.get_children():
            reset(item)
            tag = set_tag(item, tag)
            self.value_set(_TAGS, str(self.item(item, 'tags')), item)

    def tag_replace(self, old, new, item=None):
        for item in (item,) if item else self.tag_has(old):
            if self.tag_has(old, item):
                self.tags_update('add', new, item)
                self.tags_update('remove', old, item)

    def tags_update(self, opt, tags, item):
        def get_items(node):
            items.append(node)
            for node in self.get_children(node):
                get_items(node)

        if not tags:
            return
        elif isinstance(tags, str):
            tags = (tags,)

        if not item:
            items = []
            for child in self.get_children():
                get_items(child)
        else:
            items = (item,)

        for item in items:
            _tags = list(self.item(item, 'tags'))
            for _tag in tags:
                if opt == 'add':
                    if _tag not in _tags:
                        _tags.append(_tag)
                elif opt == 'remove':
                    if _tag in _tags:
                        _tags.pop(_tags.index(_tag))
            self.item(item, tags=_tags)

    def value_get(self, idx, item):
        if not item:
            return ''
        values = list(self.item(item, 'values'))
        if 0 <= idx <= len(values):
            return values[idx]

    def value_set(self, idx, value, item):
        values = list(self.item(item, 'values'))
        if idx < len(values):
            values[idx] = value
            self.item(item, values=values)

    def dlg_rename(self, title, message, current_name):

        def skip(_=None):
            self.dlg_results = _SKIP
            dlg.destroy()

        def cancel(_=None):
            self.dlg_results = _CANCEL
            dlg.destroy()

        def rename(_=None):
            self.dlg_results = dlg.entry.var.get()
            dlg.destroy()

        root = self.winfo_toplevel()
        dlg = RenameDialog(root, width=320, height=150, title=title, message=message)
        dlg.update_idletasks()
        dlg.label.config(wraplength=dlg.container.winfo_width())
        dlg.button_rename.focus()
        dlg.entry.var.set(current_name)
        dlg.entry.select_range(0, tk.END)
        dlg.entry.icursor(tk.END)
        dlg.entry.focus_set()

        dlg.bind('<Return>', rename)
        dlg.bind('<KP_Enter>', rename)

        dlg.button_rename.bind('<Button-1>', rename)
        dlg.button_rename.bind('<Return>', rename)
        dlg.button_rename.bind('<KP_Enter>', rename)

        dlg.button_skip.bind('<Button-1>', skip)
        dlg.button_skip.bind('<Return>', skip)
        dlg.button_skip.bind('<KP_Enter>', skip)

        dlg.button_cancel.bind('<Button-1>', cancel)
        dlg.button_cancel.bind('<Return>', cancel)
        dlg.button_cancel.bind('<KP_Enter>', cancel)

        if self.active_popup_widget:
            x = self.active_popup_widget.winfo_rootx()
            y = self.active_popup_widget.winfo_rooty()
        else:
            bbox = self.bbox(self.focus())
            x, y, _, _ = bbox
            x += root.winfo_rootx()
            y += root.winfo_rooty()

        widest = 0
        font = tkfont.nametofont('TkDefaultFont')
        for node in self.get_children(self.focus()):
            size = font.measure(self.item(node, 'text'))
            if size > widest:
                widest = size + font.measure('W')

        x += (widest + font.measure('W') + self.indent * self.item_depth(self.focus()))
        y += self.rowheight + self.rowheight // 2

        dlg.geometry(f'{dlg.geometry().split("+", 1)[0]}+{x}+{y}')

        root.wait_window(dlg)

        return self.dlg_results

    def dlg_message(self, title, message):
        def ok(_=None):
            dlg.destroy()

        root = self.winfo_toplevel()
        dlg = MessageDialog(root, width=320, height=130, title=title, message=message)
        dlg.update_idletasks()
        dlg.label.config(wraplength=dlg.container.winfo_width())
        dlg.button_ok.focus()

        dlg.button_ok.config(command=ok)
        dlg.button_ok.bind('<Return>', ok)
        dlg.button_ok.bind('<KP_Enter>', ok)

        if self.active_popup_widget:
            x = self.active_popup_widget.winfo_rootx()
            y = self.active_popup_widget.winfo_rooty()
        else:
            bbox = self.bbox(self.focus())
            x, y, _, _ = bbox
            x += root.winfo_rootx()
            y += root.winfo_rooty()

        item = self.identify('item', x, y-self.winfo_rooty())

        widest = 0
        font = tkfont.nametofont('TkDefaultFont')
        for node in self.get_children(self.parent(item)):
            size = font.measure(self.item(node, 'text'))
            if size > widest:
                widest = size + font.measure('W')

        x += widest
        y += self.rowheight + self.rowheight // 2

        dlg.geometry(f'{dlg.geometry().split("+", 1)[0]}+{x}+{y}')

        root.wait_window(dlg)

    def cut(self, _=None):
        def set_selections(_item):
            self.tag_add('selected', _item)
            for _item in self.get_children(_item):
                set_selections(_item)

        selections = list(self.selection())
        for item in reversed(selections):
            if self.parent(item) in selections:
                selections.pop(selections.index(item))
            else:
                set_selections(item)

        item = self.focus()
        item = self.prev(item)

        if not item and self.get_children():
            item = self.get_children()[0]

        self.undo_data = {}
        for node in selections:
            self.undo_data[node] = (self.parent(node), self.index(node))

        self.detach(*selections)
        self.detached = selections

        self.focus(item)
        self.selection_add(item)
        self.tags_reset(excluded='selected')

    def copy(self, _=None):
        def set_selected(_item):
            self.selected.append(_item)
            self.tag_add('selected', _item)
            self.value_set(_TAGS, str(self.item(_item, 'tags')), _item)
            if not self.item(_item, 'open'):
                for node in self.get_children(_item):
                    set_selected(node)

        if not self.shift:
            for item in self.tag_has('selected'):
                self.tag_remove('selected', item)
                self.value_set(_TAGS, str(self.item(item, 'tags')), item)

        self.selected = []
        for item in self.selection():
            set_selected(item)

    def undo(self, _=None):
        for item, (parent, idx) in self.undo_data.items():
            self.reattach(item, parent, idx)
            self.selection_remove(item)
        self.tags_reset()

    def paste(self, _=None):
        selections = self.detached if self.detached else self.selected

        if not self.selected and not self.detached:
            selections = self.tag_has('selected')

        for dst_item in self.selection():
            if not len(selections) or self.value_get(_TYPE, dst_item) != 'Node':
                continue

            if self.detached:
                for item in selections:
                    self.reattach(item, dst_item, tk.END)
                self.detached = False
            else:
                selected = {}
                for item in selections:
                    parent = self.parent(item)
                    dst = selected[parent] if parent in selected else dst_item
                    self.value_set(_MODIFIED, datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"), item)

                    iid = self.insert(dst, **self.item(item))
                    if iid:
                        self.value_set(_IID, iid, iid)
                        self.tag_remove('selected', iid)
                        selected[item] = iid

            self.tags_reset(excluded='selected')
            self.selection_remove(self.tag_has('selected'))
            self.selection_set(self.focus())

    def delete(self, *items):
        for item in items:
            parent = self.parent(item)
            if parent:
                value = int(self.value_get(_SIZE, parent).split(' ')[0])-1
                word = 'item' if value == 1 else 'items'
                self.value_set(_SIZE, f'{value} {word}', parent)

        super(Treeview, self).delete(*items)

    def insert(self, parent, index=tk.END, **kwargs):
        kwargs.pop('children', None)

        unique_columns = []
        for idx, c in enumerate(self.columns):
            if 'unique' in c and c['unique']:
                unique_columns.append(idx)

        for column in unique_columns:
            if column:
                pass
            else:
                text = kwargs['text']
                children = self.get_children(parent)

                column_values = []
                for node in children:
                    column_values.append(self.item(node, 'text'))

                for node in children:
                    while text == self.item(node, 'text'):
                        result = self.dlg_rename(
                            'Rename',
                            f'The name "{text}" already exists, please choose another '
                            f'name and try again.',
                            text,
                        )
                        if result in (_SKIP, _CANCEL):
                            return

                        text = result
                        kwargs['text'] = text

        iid = super(Treeview, self).insert(parent, index, **kwargs)

        child_count = len(self.get_children(parent))
        if child_count:
            word = 'item' if child_count == 1 else 'items'
            self.value_set(_SIZE, f'{len(self.get_children(parent))} {word}', parent)
        self.see(iid)
        return iid

    def escape(self, _):
        self.tags_reset()
        self.selection_remove(*self.selection())
        self.selection_set(self.focus())

    def control_a(self, _):
        def select(_child):
            self.selection_add(_child)
            for node in self.get_children(_child):
                select(node)
        for child in self.get_children():
            select(child)

    def shift_up(self, _):
        rowheight = self.style.lookup('Treeview', 'rowheight')

        focus = self.focus()
        x, y, _, _ = self.bbox(focus)
        x += self.winfo_rootx()

        _prev = self.identify('item', x, y-rowheight+1)
        if _prev:
            self.see(_prev)
            self.focus(_prev)
            self.cursor_offset += 1

            if self.cursor_offset > 0:
                self.selection_toggle(_prev)
            else:
                self.selection_toggle(focus)

            return 'break'

    def shift_down(self, _):
        rowheight = self.style.lookup('Treeview', 'rowheight')

        focus = self.focus()
        x, y, _, _ = self.bbox(focus)
        x += self.winfo_rootx()

        _next = self.identify('item', x, y+rowheight+1)
        if _next:
            self.see(_next)
            self.focus(_next)
            self.cursor_offset -= 1

            if self.cursor_offset >= 0:
                self.selection_toggle(focus)
            else:
                self.selection_toggle(_next)

            return 'break'

    def key_press(self, event):
        if 'Shift' in event.keysym:
            self.shift = True
            self.cursor_offset = 0

    def key_release(self, event):
        if 'Shift' in event.keysym:
            self.shift = False

    def expand_tree(self, _):
        def func():
            item = self.identify('item', self.winfo_pointerx(), self.winfo_pointery()-self.winfo_rooty())
            self.value_set(_OPEN, True, item)
            self.tags_reset(excluded='selected')
        self.after(1, func)

    def collapse_tree(self, _=None):
        def func():
            item = self.identify('item', self.winfo_pointerx(), self.winfo_pointery()-self.winfo_rooty())
            self.value_set(_OPEN, False, item)
            self.tags_reset(excluded='selected')
        self.after(1, func)

    def column_expand(self, event):
        def walk(_children):
            _largest = 0
            idx = int(column.lstrip('#'))-1

            for child in _children:
                if column == '#0':
                    _text = self.item(child, 'text')
                elif len(self.item(child, 'values')) > 1:
                    _text = self.item(child, 'values')[idx]
                else:
                    continue

                _length = font.measure(_text) + (indent * self.item_depth(child)) if column == '#0' else font.measure(_text)

                if _length > _largest:
                    _largest = _length

                _children = self.get_children(child)
                if not _children or not int(self.item(child, 'open')):
                    continue

                _length = walk(_children)
                if _length > _largest:
                    _largest = _length

            return _largest

        region = self.identify('region', event.x, event.y)

        if region != 'separator':
            return

        largest = 0
        column = self.identify('column', event.x, event.y)
        font = tkfont.nametofont('TkTextFont')
        font_width = font.measure('W')
        row_height = font.metrics('linespace')
        indent = row_height + font_width

        self.style.configure('Treeview', indent=indent)

        for item in self.get_children():
            text = self.item(item, 'text') if column == '#0' else self.item(item, 'values')[0]
            length = font.measure(text)+indent
            largest = length if length > largest else largest

            children = self.get_children(item)
            if not children or not int(self.item(item, 'open')):
                continue

            length = walk(children)
            if length > largest:
                largest = length

        self.column(column, width=largest+font_width)

    def detach(self, *items):
        if not items:
            items = self.selection()

        self.undo_data = {}
        for item in items:
            self.undo_data[item] = (self.parent(item), self.index(item))

            parent = self.parent(item)
            if parent:
                value = int(self.value_get(_SIZE, parent).split(' ')[0])-1
                word = 'item' if value == 1 else 'items'
                self.value_set(_SIZE, f'{value} {word}', parent)

        item = self.focus()
        item = self.prev(item)

        super(Treeview, self).detach(*self.selection())

        self.focus(item)
        self.selection_add(item)
        self.tags_reset(excluded='selected')

    def reattach(self, item, parent, index):
        for idx, column in enumerate(self.columns):
            if 'unique' in column and column['unique']:
                if idx:
                    pass
                else:
                    text = self.item(item, 'text')
                    children = self.get_children(parent)

                    column_values = []
                    for node in children:
                        column_values.append(self.item(node, 'text'))

                    for node in children:
                        while text == self.item(node, 'text'):
                            result = self.dlg_rename(
                                'Rename',
                                f'The name "{text}" already exists, please choose another '
                                f'name and try again.',
                                text,
                            )
                            if result in (_SKIP, _CANCEL):
                                return

                            text = result
                            self.item(item, text=text)

        iid = self.move(item, parent, index)

        return iid

    def wheel_mouse(self, event):
        if not self.item(self.focus(), 'text'):
            self.delete(self.focus())

        value = -0.1/3 if event.num == 5 else 0.1/3
        self.yview('moveto', self.yview()[0] + value)

        return 'break'

    def button_click(self, _):

        if self.active_popup_widget:
            item = self.focus()
            item_text = self.item(item, 'text')
            wdg_text = self.active_popup_widget.var.get().strip(' ')

            column = int(self.active_popup_column.lstrip('#'))
            unique = self.columns[column].get('unique', False)

            self.active_popup_widget.destroy()
            self.active_popup_widget = None

            if item_text == wdg_text and not item_text:
                self.delete(item)
                self.tags_reset()
                return

            if not item_text and not wdg_text:
                self.delete(item)
                self.tags_reset()
                return

            if not item_text:
                if unique:
                    for node in self.get_children(self.parent(item)):
                        if wdg_text == self.item(node, 'text'):
                            self.delete(item)
                            self.tags_reset()
                            return
                else:
                    return

            if unique:
                for node in self.get_children(self.parent(item)):
                    if wdg_text == self.item(node, 'text'):
                        return

            if not column and wdg_text:
                self.item(self.focus(), text=wdg_text)
            else:
                self.value_set(column-1, wdg_text, self.focus())

            self.active_popup_widget = None
            self.tags_reset()

    def button_release(self, event):
        self.focus(self.identify('item', event.x, event.y))

    def button_double_click(self, event):
        region = self.identify_region(event.x, event.y)

        if region == 'tree' or region == 'cell':
            row = self.identify_row(event.y)
            column = self.identify_column(event.x)

            wdg = self.active_popup_widget = self.popup_widget(row, column)
            if wdg:
                self.active_popup_column = column
                if isinstance(wdg, Entry):
                    wdg.select_range(0, tk.END)

        elif region == 'separator':
            self.column_expand(event)
        elif region == 'heading':
            pass
            self.after(1, self.tags_reset)

        return 'break'

    def item_depth(self, item):
        depth = 1
        parent = self.parent(item)
        while parent:
            depth += 1
            parent = self.parent(parent)

        return depth

    def insert_node(self):
        item = self.identify('item', self.popup.x, self.popup.y-self.winfo_rooty())

        if not item:
            parent = ''
            idx = tk.END
        elif self.value_get(_TYPE, item) == 'Node':
            idx = 0
            parent = item
        else:
            idx = self.index(item) + 1
            parent = self.parent(item)

        iid = self.insert(
            parent,
            idx,
            open=True,
            **{'text': '', 'values': (['', 'Node', True, '', '', datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"), ''])},
        )

        self.focus(iid)
        self.value_set(_IID, iid, iid)
        self.tags_reset()

        self.active_popup_widget = self.popup_widget(iid, '#0')

    def insert_leaf(self):
        item = self.identify('item', self.popup.x, self.popup.y-self.winfo_rooty())

        if not item:
            parent = ''
            idx = tk.END
        elif self.value_get(_TYPE, item) == 'Node':
            idx = 0
            parent = item
        else:
            idx = self.index(item) + 1
            parent = self.parent(item)

        iid = self.insert(
            parent,
            idx,
            **{'text': '', 'values': (['', 'Leaf', '', '', '0 Kb', datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H-%M-%S"), ''])},
        )

        self.focus(iid)
        self.value_set(_IID, iid, iid)
        self.tags_reset()
        self.active_popup_widget = self.popup_widget(iid, '#0')

    def populate(self, parent, data=()):
        for item in data:
            iid = self.insert(parent, tk.END, **item)
            self.value_set(_IID, iid, iid)

            if 'children' in item:
                self.populate(iid, item['children'])

    def serialize(self):
        def get_data(_item, _data):
            for node in self.get_children(_item):
                _item_data = self.item(node)
                _data.append(_item_data)
                if self.get_children(node):
                    _item_data['children'] = []
                    get_data(node, _item_data['children'])

        data = {'headings': self.headings, 'columns': self.columns, 'data': {}}

        tree_data = []
        for item in self.get_children():
            item_data = self.item(item)
            if self.get_children(item):
                item_data['children'] = []
                tree_data.append(item_data)
                get_data(item, item_data['children'])
            else:
                tree_data.append(item_data)

        data['data'] = tree_data

        return data

    def popup_menu(self, event):
        region = self.identify_region(event.x, event.y)
        if region == 'heading':
            return

        if self.active_popup_widget:
            self.active_popup_widget.destroy()
            self.active_popup_widget = None

        self.popup.x, self.popup.y = event.x_root, event.y_root
        item = self.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
        self.focus(item)
        self.focus_set()
        self.popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)

    def popup_widget(self, row, column):
        if not row or not column:
            return

        bbox = self.bbox(row, column)
        if not bbox:
            return

        if self.active_popup_widget:
            self.active_popup_widget.destroy()

        x_pos, y_pos, width, height = self.bbox(row, column)
        item = self.identify('item', x_pos, y_pos+self.rowheight)
        y_pos += height // 2

        if column == '#0':
            col = 0
            text = self.item(item, 'text')
            x_pos += self.indent // 2
            width -= self.indent // 2 + 1
        else:
            col = int(column.lstrip('#'))
            text = self.value_get(col-1, item)
            x_pos += 1

        wdg = None
        mode = self.columns[col].get('mode', tk.WRITABLE)
        unique = self.columns[col].get('unique', False)
        _type = self.columns[col].get('type', None)

        if _type == 'Entry':
            def tab(_):
                if int(column.lstrip('#')) >= len(self.columns)-1:
                    self.active_popup_widget = self.popup_widget(self.focus(), '#0')
                    self.active_popup_column = '#0'
                else:
                    for idx, data in enumerate(self.columns[int(column.lstrip('#'))+1:]):
                        if 'type' in data:
                            self.active_popup_widget = self.popup_widget(self.focus(), f'#{idx+1}')
                            self.active_popup_column = f'#{idx+1}'
                            self.active_popup_widget.focus_set()
                            self.active_popup_widget.select_range(0, tk.END)

                return 'break'

            def update(_):
                _item = self.focus()
                wdg_text = wdg.var.get().strip(' ')
                item_text = self.item(_item, 'text')

                if item_text != wdg_text:

                    if not item_text and not wdg_text:
                        wdg.destroy()
                        self.active_popup_widget = None
                        self.delete(_item)
                        return

                    elif item_text and not wdg_text:
                        self.item(_item, text=item_text)
                        wdg.destroy()
                        self.active_popup_widget = None
                        self.focus_set()
                        self.focus(_item)
                        return

                    if not col:
                        if unique:
                            parent = self.parent(_item)
                            children = self.get_children(parent)

                            column_values = []
                            for node in children:
                                column_values.append(self.item(node, 'text'))

                            for node in children:
                                while wdg_text == self.item(node, 'text'):
                                    result = self.dlg_rename(
                                        'Rename',
                                        f'The name "{wdg_text}" already exists, please choose another '
                                        f'name and try again.',
                                        wdg_text,
                                    )
                                    if result == '':
                                        continue

                                    if result in (_SKIP, _CANCEL):
                                        return

                                    wdg_text = result
                                    self.item(item, text=text)

                                if wdg_text == self.item(node, 'text'):
                                    return

                        self.item(_item, text=wdg_text)
                    else:
                        self.value_set(col-1, wdg.get(), _item)

                wdg.destroy()
                self.active_popup_widget = None
                self.tags_reset()
                self.focus_set()
                self.selection_set(_item)

            def destroy(_=None):
                wdg.destroy()
                self.active_popup_widget = None

                _item = self.focus()
                _text = self.item(_item, 'text')
                self.tags_reset()
                if not _text:
                    self.delete(item)

                self.tags_reset()
                self.focus_set()

            def control_a(_=None):
                def func():
                    wdg.select_range(0, tk.END)
                    wdg.icursor(tk.END)
                self.after(1, func)

            def move_focus(event):
                if event.keysym == 'Up':
                    update(event)
                    _item = self.focus()

                    wdg.destroy()
                    self.active_popup_widget = None
                    self.focus_set()
                    prev = self.prev(self.focus())
                    if prev:
                        self.selection_set(prev)
                        self.focus(prev)

                else:
                    update(event)
                    _item = self.focus()

                    wdg.destroy()
                    self.active_popup_widget = None
                    self.focus_set()
                    _next = self.next(self.focus())
                    if _next:
                        self.selection_set(_next)
                        self.focus(_next)

            if mode == tk.WRITABLE:
                wdg = Entry(self)
                wdg.place(x=x_pos+4, y=y_pos, anchor='w', width=width-4)
                wdg.var.set(text)
                wdg.icursor(tk.END)
                wdg.focus()
                wdg.focus_set()

                bindings = {
                    '<Up>': move_focus,
                    '<Down>': move_focus,
                    '<Tab>': tab,
                    # '<Control-ISO_Left_Tab>': tab,
                    '<Return>': update,
                    '<KP_Enter>': update,
                    '<Escape>': destroy,
                    '<Control-z>': destroy,
                    '<Control-a>': control_a,
                }
                for command, callback in bindings.items():
                    wdg.bind(command, callback)

        elif _type == 'Combobox':
            def tab(_):
                if int(column.lstrip('#')) >= len(self.columns)-1:
                    self.active_popup_widget = self.popup_widget(self.focus(), '#0')
                else:
                    for idx, data in enumerate(self.columns[int(column.lstrip('#'))+1:]):
                        if 'type' in data:
                            self.active_popup_widget = self.popup_widget(self.focus(), f'#{idx+1}')
                self.active_popup_widget.focus_set()
                self.active_popup_widget.select_range(0, tk.END)

                return 'break'

            def update(_):
                _text = wdg.get().strip(' ')
                if not col:
                    self.item(self.focus(), text=_text)
                else:
                    self.value_set(col-1, _text, self.focus())
                destroy()
                self.focus_set()

            def destroy(_=None):
                wdg.destroy()
                self.active_popup_widget = None
                self.focus_set()

            def control_a(_=None):
                def func():
                    wdg.select_range(0, tk.END)
                    wdg.icursor(tk.END)
                self.after(1, func)

            state = '' if mode == tk.WRITABLE else 'readonly'
            values = self.columns[col].get('values', '')
            wdg = Combobox(self, state=state, values=values)
            wdg.place(x=x_pos, y=y_pos, anchor='w', width=width-2)
            wdg.var.set(text)
            wdg.icursor(tk.END)

            bindings = {
                '<Tab>': tab,
                # '<Control-ISO_Left_Tab>': tab,
                '<Return>': update,
                '<KP_Enter>': update,
                '<Escape>': destroy,
                '<Control-z>': destroy,
                '<Control-a>': control_a,
            }
            for command, callback in bindings.items():
                wdg.bind(command, callback)

        return wdg

    def popup_widget_edit(self, _):
        self.active_popup_widget = self.popup_widget(self.focus(), '#0')
        self.active_popup_widget.select_range(0, tk.END)
        self.active_popup_widget.icursor(tk.END)
        self.active_popup_widget.focus_set()
        self.active_popup_column = '#0'

        return 'break'

    def popup_destroy(self, _):
        if self.active_popup_widget:
            self.active_popup_widget.destroy()
            self.active_popup_widget = None

    def bindings_set(self):
        bindings = {
            '<Up>': self.popup_destroy,
            '<Down>': self.popup_destroy,
            '<Key>': self.key_press,
            '<Tab>': self.popup_widget_edit,
            '<Escape>': self.escape,
            '<Return>': self.popup_widget_edit,
            '<KP_Enter>': self.popup_widget_edit,
            '<Button-1>': self.button_click,
            '<Button-4>': self.wheel_mouse,
            '<Button-5>': self.wheel_mouse,
            '<Shift-Up>': self.shift_up,
            '<Shift-Down>': self.shift_down,
            '<Control-a>': self.control_a,
            '<Control-x>': self.cut,
            '<Control-c>': self.copy,
            '<Control-v>': self.paste,
            '<Control-z>': self.undo,
            '<KeyRelease>': self.key_release,
            '<ButtonPress-3>': self.popup_menu,
            '<Double-Button-1>': self.button_double_click,
            '<ButtonRelease-1>': self.button_release,
            '<<TreeviewOpen>>': self.expand_tree,
            '<<TreeviewClose>>': self.collapse_tree,
        }
        for command, callback in bindings.items():
            self.bind(command, callback)


def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I like test cases that exemplify usage. And [doc strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring).

Answer (score 3):

### Enumerations

You're 99% of the way to a useful `Enum`, here:

```
_IID = 0
_TYPE = 1
_OPEN = 2
_TAGS = 3
_SIZE = 4
_MODIFIED = 5
_DATA1 = 6
```

I'm not really clear on what they're used for - maybe `NodeKey`? Put them in an `Enum`.

### No-op `if`

```
    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        self.platform = 'linux'
```

doesn't need the first predicate; simply

```
if platform == 'linux2':
    self.platform = 'linux'
```

or even

```
if 'linux' in platform:
    self.platform = 'linux'
```

However, it seems you don't even use `self.platform`, so the works could get deleted.

### pathlib

Rather than using `path.join`, consider using `pathlib.Path`, which has a much nicer object-oriented interface for path manipulation.

### Default for `get`

```
settings.get('focus', None)
```

does not need to write `None` since that is the default.

### Multi-assignment

```
    self.popup = \
        self.menu_background = None
```

doesn't really have any advantages; just use individual assignment.

### Single dict

```
    bindings = {
        '<ButtonPress-3>': self.popup_menu,
    }
    for command, callback in bindings.items():
        self.bind(command, callback)
```

is odd. Why not just

```
self.bind('<ButtonPress-3>', self.popup_menu)
```

?

Even if you had a long series of bindings, a dict would not be appropriate - you could just use a tuple of tuples.

### More `if` logic

```
            if idx:
                pass
            else:
```

should just be

```
if not idx:
```

### Event numbers

```
event.num == 5
```

is mysterious. I'd be surprised if tk did not have a constant for this already, but if it doesn't, you should declare one.

### kwargs

```
    iid = self.insert(
        parent,
        idx,
        open=True,
        **{'text': '', 'values': (['', 'Node', True, '', '', datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"), ''])},
    )
```

In this case, there is no advantage to using a dict. Just use regular unquoted kwargs.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll make them recommendations happen.

Comment: I have made all the changes you suggested thanks once again. I have updated the code if you have the time please look at it and let me know if I have accomplished the things you spoke of.  https://github.com/unodan/TkInter-Treeview-Example-Demo